# Add text to scatter point using python gmplot

Tags: python

I plotted some points on google maps using gmplot's scatter method (python). I want to add some text to the points so when someone clicks on those points they can see the text.

I am unable to find any documentation or example that shows how to do this.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Just looking for the answer to this myself. **gmplot** was updated to June  2016 to include a hovertext functionality for the marker method, but unfortunately this isn't available for the scatter method. The enthusiastic user will find that the scatter method simply calls the marker method over and over, and could modify the scatter method itself to accept a title or range of titles.

If like myself you are using an older version, make sure to run

`pip install --upgrade gmplot`

and to place a marker with hovertext (mouse hovering over pin without clicking)

`gmap=gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter("Seattle")
gmap.marker(47.61028142523736, -122.34147349538826, title="A street corner in Seattle")
st="testmap.html"
gmap.draw(st)`

Comment: Is there any correlation between marker size and circle diameter on the map?
For example is size=60 equal to circle of diameter 60?